# CloudPageURL via SMS broken link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, cloudpage, sms

I've found that using `CloudPagesURL` via SMS will always result in the Server Error 500 page, no matter if the `URLEncode` is used or not, even if the CloudPage itself just holds simple text.

CloudPage is published and in the same MID.

No additional parameters aside from the CloudPage ID are being passed, yet I see the full URL of it does contain *something* else.

SMS Example:

```
%%[
var @link
set @link = CloudPagesURL(2298)
]%%
```

The output of the link will be: `https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/r4a1bz43j0p?qs=ac100395ce51f9cd5513c02ebeb86e36e2b6f299cccd594e`

While the actual page is just `https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/r4a1bz43j0p`

Why does it get some parameter added?

Why does the page *with* this parameter always end up in Server Error 500?

Also, an interesting detail - when sending out test SMS, then I am able to access the page.

Comment: Are you doing anything with AMPScript in the CloudPage?

Comment: Hi Adam, there's no script on the CloudPage itself. It's only plain text currently on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well then, got this issue solved.

When using `CloudPagesURL` ampscript function link creation via MobileConnect, then the Contact this SMS is sent to, **needs** to exist in Email channel AllSubscribers list with the same SubscriberKey/ContactKey.

Apparently the `CloudPagesURL` will use Email channel data to generate the URL, thus when it cannot find a matching Contact in AllSubscribers list - the link it generates will be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it get some parameter added?
- Normally CloudPagesURL will add parameters like jobid, listid, sk (subscriberkey) when being sent from Email Studio. I tried getting these values when sending from MobileConnect but it seems none of them were there. I would recommend opening a ticket with SF to get information on what values are added in MobileConnect

Why does the page with this parameter always end up in Server Error 500? 
- In my testing there was no issues when using `CloudPage %%=CloudPagesURL(55)=%%` in MobileConnect.My Guess is that the Cloud Page itself has issues in it, potentially one of the parameters passed in the QS is causing conflict. Does the cloud page contain anything like `%%=RequestParameter('sk')=%%`?

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your input. Cloud Page itself has no script whatsoever, only plain text 'hello world' on it. And to make things even weirder, no additional parameters except the Cloud Page ID are being passed in the CloudPagesURL function call.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following and see whether it works?

```
%%[
SET @link = RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(2298))
]%%
```

Comment: Unofortunately no, it did not work in SMS. If I'm not mistaken, then the RedirectTo function works in HTML emails and landing pages only.

Comment: It might be that the CloudPagesURL function doesn't work at all with SMSes, and the direct link to the page is required with a encoded parameter passed through (using Base64Encode(), for instance).

Comment: It does work, the correct URL itself is generated. If you see my example in first post, the long URL that was generated can be for an example modified, remove the QS and it works. But this kills any personalization (if passed via CloudPagesURL) - and in addition, this all works perfectly fine in another MID.